# Error with 'layout_height' attribute should be defined

Tags: java, android, xml

Error with 'layout_height' attribute should be defined

I used to create new Android project  and change ConstraintLayout to LinearLayout
but it's show error with Radiobutton

"'layout_height' attribute should be defined less Validates resource references inside Android XML files."

How can i do . thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/orientation"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="50dp">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/horizontal"      <<< error 
            android:text="ddd" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/vertical"        <<< error 
            android:text="d" />
    </RadioGroup>
        <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/gravity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="50dp">
            <RadioButton                         <<< error 
                android:id="@+id/left"
                android:text="dd" />
            <RadioButton                             <<< error 
                android:id="@+id/center"
                android:text="cc" /> 
            <RadioButton                                 <<< error 
                android:id="@+id/right"
                android:text="cc" />
        </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` .every view requires height and width attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` attributes for the radio buttons, and you can see the error magically disappears :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the layout height and width. The edited code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RadioGroup 
        android:id="@+id/orientation"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="50dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/horizontal"       
            android:text="ddd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/vertical" 
            android:text="d"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup 
            android:id="@+id/gravity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="50dp">
            <RadioButton                         
                android:id="@+id/left"
                android:text="dd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <RadioButton                             
                android:id="@+id/center"
                android:text="cc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
            <RadioButton                                  
                android:id="@+id/right"
                android:text="cc" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to set RadioButton  without height and and  weight add these to attributes in RadioButton.